# Magento2 admin flush cache

Tags: magento2, admin, cache

Is there a cron job that I can turn on or some setting that I must set, so when I make changes in Magento2 admin panel while in developer mode, that I do not have to go to cache page and flush cache manually every single time ?

Comment: If you could disable the cache completely,  I think that would work too.

Comment: yeah, probably, but I think this will make the process even slower, I am looking for some more useful solution

Comment: No, I think Magento 2 works fine. This happens with Magento 1 older versions. I think you should try and see it that works. Otherwise, wait for the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Lachezar Raychev You are advised to disable the caches while in development stage. You can do this by simplying using the following commands from the magento root - ssh.

- Disable: php bin/magento cache:disable
- Enable: php bin/magento cache:enable
- Flush: php bin/magento cache:flush

Or simply disabling it from admin under Systems > Cache Management.

This will be easier than creating an observer that runs a cron job after a save event.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the full page cache and configuration cache from admin.